# Using function to take Input in LinkedList but giving Segmentation Fault error while printing it

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, runtime-error

This is a circular doubly linkedlist but it is giving a runtime error of ***Segmentation Fault*** while running the program. The use of function is to take input till the user gives -1 and print function to print till the cur->next == head. Kindly tell me what am I doing wrong so that I wouldn't do it in future. ThankYou!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class CDNode{
public:
    T data;
    CDNode* next;
    CDNode* prev;

    CDNode(T x){
       data = x;
       next = nullptr;
       prev = nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename T>
CDNode<T>* takeInput(){
    cout<<"Enter the elements of the list"<<endl;
    T data;
    cin>>data;
    CDNode<T> *head = nullptr;
    CDNode<T> *tail = nullptr;

    while(data != -1){
        CDNode<T> *newNode = new CDNode<T>(data);
        if(head == nullptr){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }else{
            tail->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = tail;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        cin>>data;
    }
    return head;
    }

template<typename T>
void print(CDNode<T> *head,CDNode<T> *cur){
    if(cur->next == head){
      cout<<cur->data<<endl;
      return;
    }
    cout<<cur->data<<" <- ";
    return print(head,cur->next);
}

int main(){
    CDNode<int> *head = takeInput<int>();
    print(head,head);
    }
```

Comment: What did you observe when running your program in the debugger, stepping through line by line and watching how variables change?

Comment: I am new to programming and I don't know how to debug the code. If you could teach me  something about it then it would be helpful.

Comment: That's an essential skill and should be easily doable using any decent IDE.

Comment: I don't have an IDE I am using linux and using Geany and Visual Studio Code and some times Code Blocks but I am not able to use Code Blocks efficiently as it is so confusing.

Comment: Visual Studio Code and Code Blocks can be configured to use a debugger IIRC (and these are IDEs BTW).

Comment: Oh Thanks Alot I will do that and start debugging my codes

Comment: You claim you are building a circular list, and `print` in fact relies on that, but `takeInput` doesn't actually build one. The last node's `next` pointer is `nullptr`, not pointing back to `head`.

Comment: How to use a debugger: Make an input set that triggers the error you wish to solve. Prefer to build the input directly into the program so you don't have to keep entering it over and over. Make a list of expectations, basically outline what is supposed to happen at each point in your code. Start the program with the debugger. Step through the program line by line and watch what happens. When the actions of the program do not match your expectations (too the wrong path, set the wrong value) you have probably found a bug. Adjust the program so the behaviour matches your expectations.

Comment: When working with linked list and other graph structures, it is really helpful to draw pictures. They help you visualize the list. Draw it slowly, node by node and connection by connection and you can see the the order in which you need to do things in the code. If you cannot follow your coded instructions to produce the same drawing, you have a bug and you probably can see what you needed to do instead.

Comment: Thanks alot @user4581301. It is really helpful. Just tell me what is the ideal ide to use in linux.

Answer (score 0):

In a circular list tail->next should point to head node which makes it circle.Your code is just a double list .